# Modify css file of Magento2 Module

Tags: css, magento2

I'm trying to customize the css style of Magento2 module.

I have my custom .phtml into:  `/app/design/frontend/VENDOR/CUSTOM_THEME/templates/product/list.phtml` and it work.

After that I have created a .less file into:  `/app/design/frontend/VENDOR/CUSTOM_THEME/web/css/source/_theme.less`
and I have written a simple `.product{ background-color: #FF0000; }` but I can't see the style on the site.

I have tried to reflush cache and under `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer` .I have set Workflow type: `"Client side less compilation"`

I have also tried to launch `magento dev:source-theme:deploy --theme="VENDOR/CUSTOM_THEME"` but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included _theme.less in _sources.less file